# Get value form multiple child which is having same parent name and child name in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want fetch the value only for "Publisher " since I have the same class name and for both the parent, I am not able to figure how to do it.

```
<div class="block-record-info">
   <div class="title3">Publisher</div>
     <p class="FR_field">
     <value>INFORMS, 5521 RESEARCH PARK DR, SUITE 200, CATONSVILLE, MD 21228 USA</value>
     </p>

</div>
<div class="block-record-info">
    <div class="title3">Categories / Classification</div>
       <p class="FR_field">
       <span class="FR_label">Research Areas:</span>
Computer Science; Operations Research & Management Science
</p>
```

the code I used :

> valuexpath1 = '//div[@class="block-record-info"]' valueElement1 =
>   driver.find_element_by_xpath(valuexpath1) valuexpath2 = '//*'
>   valueElement2 = valueElement1.find_element_by_xpath(valuexpath2)
>   valueValue2 = valueElement2.text print(valueValue2)

it is giving me the value of "Categories / Classification" and "Publisher ". but I want only publisher.

Comment: Can you please share the extended HTML. Looks like the parent for div elements will help you find the unique path.

Answer (score 0):

As the first `div` doesn't have `span` element, you can try exclude `div` which contain `p/span`:

```
valuexpath1 = '//div[@class="block-record-info" and not(p/span)]'
```

Comment: i have another class with "block-record-info" and not(p/span) ... now what can i do ? i cant find a work around .. please help me